# why pow function of math.h return infinity value?

Tags: c++, pow, math.h

I Want to Calculate x^y.

x is -0.726354 and y is 0.954.

So, I Using pow Function. but return infinity value.

how to calculate when x value is negative.

Please Answer to me.

Thanks.

Comment: provide the source code you used...

Comment: Looks like a homework!

Comment: What value would you expect?

Answer (score 6):

Powers of negative numbers with non-integer exponent are generally complex numbers. The `pow` function returns a `double` which is an approximation of a real number. Therefore this cannot work.

If you are only interested in the absolute value, you can rewrite it as:

x^y = (-x)^y * (-1)^y

You can calculate the left term using `pow` because -x is positive. The right term has an absolute value of 1.

By the way, the `pow`function does not return an "infinity" value but a value that indicates a domain error.

Comment: First. Thanks for Corret to me. I will find about indicates a domain error. and Is this equation( (-1)^y ) Always return 1???

Comment: @user1320165: The value of (-1)^y is not really 1 but a complex number with an absolute value of 1. In the complex plane, these are values on the unit circle.

Comment: According to your answer. 1 is an approximate value. I understand it. Thank you.

Comment: @user1320165: No, not an approximate value but an absolute value. An example: Both -1 and 1 have the same absolute value of 1. With complex numbers, you have not only these two cases but an infinite number of them.

Comment: Is you explained this?? if x < 0 case x^y = |x|^y * (-1)^y. I don't know about complex numbers.... so I can't understand it.

Comment: @user1320165: Without some basic knowledge of complex numbers, you won't be able to understand you original question. In fact, a variant of this question is what made Gauss come up with complex numbers in the 19th century.

Comment: I understand what you means. I will  Learn Complex number. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`pow` for floating point arguments is probably implemented as `exp (y log x)` (this is, by the way, remarkably clever since `log` and `exp` in particular can be evaluated very quickly on modern chipsets). Clearly that does not work for non-positive `x`, hence your output.

The standard specifies that `pow` is only defined for a positive `x` if `x` and `y` are floating point. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow is a good reference.

Comment: Thanks. I  tried to exp(y ln x) but failed. because ln(-0.7) returned indicates a domain error. According to reference written in pow(-1, ±∞). ±∞ means any number?? even decimal??

Comment: You do understand that -0.726354 raised to 0.954 does not have a real solution? (Rather a family of complex numbers)?

Comment: Yup. That answer has a clever decomposition. But note carefully what the answerer means by the *absolute* value.

Comment: @user1320165 it means any infinity: positive or negative